# How do I run a thornthwaite function (which computes standard precipitation index) by location and latitude in R?

Tags: r, loops, weather, temperature

I have the following data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
  id YEAR    MONTH   TMED    PRCP    lat
   1  1986    1      -14.5    2.3    42.4863
   1  1986    2      -13.9    5.7    42.4863
   2  1986    1      -12.9    7.2    42.46
   2  1986    2      -11.6    19.7   42.46", header=TRUE)
```

where

- id is my location unit ranging from 1 to 90
- TMED - mean monthly temperature by location
- PRCP - precipitation by location
- lat - latitude by location
- YEAR ranges from 1986 to 2016
- MONTH ranges from 1 to 12

I need to run the following  function in R to calculate SPEI index (Standard Precipitation-Evapotranspiration Index) for each location:

```
library(SPEI)

dat$PET <- thornthwaite(dat$TMED, dat$lat[1])

dat$BAL <- dat$PRCP-dat$PET

spei1 <- spei(dat$BAL, scale = 1)

dat$spei1=l
```

This code works for one location. But I need to make a loop over latitude and location. One problem is that latitude should enter the function **thornthwaite** as a number (not as a list/variable).

Comment: Please do not post screenshots, they are not helpful. Instead provide example data as code so others can replicate and be able to help.

Comment: Done. Thanks @Pearly Spencer.

Comment: Is `thornthwaite()` the one in the `SPEI` library?

Comment: Yes, it's a SPEI library @AkselA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with the [Thornthwaite equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_evaporation) a bit for my ecology masters, and this implementation appears a bit strange. Despite how it might appear here, the equation needs more than just mean temperature and latitudes as input. It actually needs the average daylength of a given month, but this can be calculated from latitude and date, and `thornthwaite()` gets the date by just assuming the first datapoint represents January, and the rest follows in sequence. The Thornthwaite equation also depends on a yearly heat index, which means you need monthly temperature means for the entire year. `thornthwaite()` solves this by aggregating over the temperature vector you supply.

In summation, for `thornthwaite()` to work you need a sequence of monthly mean temperatures, in sequence, starting in January and spanning at least one year. As such, the function won't work on the data you supplied.

I suggest you make sure your series is long enough, and also split it into separate data.frames for each location. You can use `split()` for this (`split(dat, dat$id)`).

There are a few examples in `?thornthwaite`, including one demonstrating its use on time series, useful if your series doesn't start on January.

I made a mockup demonstrating one possible approach:
(Notice the function will return values even if the data doesn't cover a full year, these values will then be quite unreliable.)

```
dat <- read.table(text="
  id YEAR    MONTH   TMED    PRCP    lat
   1  1986    1     -14.5    2.3    42.4863
   1  1986    2     -13.9    5.7    42.4863
   1  1986    3     -10.5    2.3    42.4863
   1  1986    4      -7.9    5.7    42.4863
   1  1986    5      -4.5    2.3    42.4863
   1  1986    6       0.9    5.7    42.4863
   1  1986    7      10.5    2.3    42.4863
   1  1986    8      17.9    5.7    42.4863
   2  1986    1     -12.9    7.2    42.46
   2  1986    2     -11.6   19.7    42.46
   2  1986    3      -8.9    7.2    42.46
   2  1986    4      -5.9    7.2    42.46
   2  1986    5       1.6   19.7    42.46
   2  1986    6      12.9    7.2    42.46
   2  1986    7      21.6   19.7    42.46
   2  1986    8      25.6   19.7    42.46", header=TRUE)

dat.s <- split(dat, dat$id)

lapply(dat.s, function(x) thornthwaite(x$TMED, x$lat[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @AksleA ! Yes, I do have all months for each year - I was not presenting here to save space. I tried with a split function as you suggest but I do not know how to include the changing latitude in it. Would you recommend perhaps just to use the SPEI gridded dataset instead (already calculated by the authors of this index)? I guess I can extract the values based on my lat & long. Thanks again!

Comment: OK. But this command lapply(dat.s, function(x) thornthwaite(x$TMED, x$lat[1])) takes the first value of latitude from the split or from the original data frame?

Comment: @Anastasia: From the split. `split()` returns a list of data.frames, `lapply()` loops throught this list, applying `thornthwaite()` to each data.frame. Thornthwaite's equation will give you only a very rough approximation to potential evapotranspiration. If you have access to more reliable data you should definitely go for that.

Comment: @Anastasia: No problem. When you find an answer helpful you're encouraged to give it a green 'check' mark, by clicking the symbol at the top left, below the vote arrows.